# Apollo Compose and Enzyme mount

Tags: reactjs, graphql, enzyme, apollo

I have an issue here. I'm using React Apollo as GraphQL client and `compose` from Apollo to create my component separated from my GraphQL rules.

Everything works fine but I need to write some tests. So here's my component:

```
export const NestedComponent(someProperty: MyProperty) => (
    <div>
        Some simple content...
        { someProperty.value }
        Another content here...
    </div>
);

class ParentComponent extends Component<Props, {
    anotherProperty: string
}> {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (<NestedComponent someProperty={ value: anotherProperty } />);
    }
}

const withSomeData = graphql(myQuery, {
    props: ({ data }) => ({ someProperty: { value: data.value }),
});

export default compose(
    withSomeData,
    withApollo,
)(withTheme(WorkstreamSelector));
```

As you can see, it's a very simple component with a nested function component. No secrets. So, here's my problem, I'm using [Airbnb Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/) to test my components. For this, I use `mount` from Enzyme (this way I can mock Apollo layer and stuff the way I want) and then comes the problem.

When I simply try to mount a component that is out of Apollo's compose function, the `mount` function returns me the complete DOM of the object, but when I use compose, no matter what I do, I always get only the first level (note that I'm not using `shallow`, I'm using `mount`), and I can't test the nested components inside my parent's component.

Can someone help me?